# This key is already associated with an element of this collection error

Tags: vba

```
    Dim colResults  As New Collection
       Dim intI         As Integer
       Dim objConn      As ADODB.Connection
       Dim objCmd       As ADODB.Command
       Dim objRs        As ADODB.Recordset
       Dim strErrText   As String
       Dim oField       As ADODB.Field
       Dim sVal

       On Error GoTo RaiseError

       Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
       objConn.open DBConnString
       Set objCmd = New ADODB.Command
       Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
       objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
       objCmd.CommandText = "spSearchHistory_Read"
       objCmd.Parameters(1) = CLng(sUserID)
       Set objRs = objCmd.Execute

       intI = 1

       For Each oField In objRs.fields
        If IsNull(oField.Value) Then
                    'fix null vals so the front end doesnt trip up trying to access them
                    sVal = ""
        Else
            If oField.Type = adDBTimeStamp Then
                        sVal = Format(oField.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
            Else
                        sVal = oField.Value
            End If
        End If
                colResults.Add sVal, oField.Name
        Next

       objConn.Close
       Set SearchHistory = colResults
       Set objRs = Nothing
       Set objCmd = Nothing
       Set objConn = Nothing

       GoTo END_OF_FUNC

RaiseError:
       strErrText = "CutomerSearch.SearchHistory" & vbTab & " - " & vbTab & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
       WriteToLogFile strErrText
       WriteToEventLog strErrText

END_OF_FUNC:
```

Answer (score 0):

a collection will accept only elements with no duplicated keys

it must be that your code at some point tries to add to `colResults` a new "value" but with a "key" you already gave to a previously added element

to find out what's happening you can adopt this snippet:

```
        On Error Resume Next '<~~ temporarily suspend your error handling mode to detect duplicates
        colResults.Add sVal, oField.Name '<~~ this will result in error 457 if trying to add a new item with a key you assigned to an element already in collection
        If Err <> 0 Then
            'possible code to handle duplicates
            'On Error GoTo RaiseError '<~~ resume your error handling mode
            '... code

        End If
        On Error GoTo RaiseError '<~~ resume your error handling mode
```

from your code I could guess it's happening because you're adding elements to the collection even if `IsNull(oField.Value)`, thus making it possible to add elements with the same `Null` key

should that be the case you may want to keep `colResults.Add sVal, oField.Name` statements inside the `Else-End If` block, like follows

```
If IsNull(oField.Value) Then
            'fix null vals so the front end doesnt trip up trying to access them
            sVal = ""
Else
    If oField.Type = adDBTimeStamp Then
                sVal = Format(oField.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
    Else
                sVal = oField.Value
    End If
    colResults.Add sVal, oField.Name '<~~ add elements only if oField.Value is not Null
End If
```

Comment: @ravindersingh: did you get through it?